# Anaconda update problems

Tags: upgrade, conda

This is more of a general question about workflow than perhaps a detailed bug report. This has happened to me three times: I download Anaconda, work with it beautifully, perhaps installing one or two additional packages, but mostly working with Jupyter and Scipy/Numpy/Matplotlib. Then one day conda updates itself to next release (4.0 -> 4.1, or 4.0 ->4.2 depending on the machine) and all goes suddenly wrong. Should I refrain from using conda update and reinstall Anaconda from scratch? Is this a known issue? Is there another procedure or routine I should use, such as updating every few weeks?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that certain other packages(dependencies) need to be updated as well.

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

You can also prevent conda from automatically updating by adding the following to your .condarc file(should be where you installed Anaconda or your user directory and it may be hidden)

```
auto_update_conda: False
```